# OroCommerce about the frontend extend or chaplin

Tags: orocommerce

The best way to work on the frontend, is via render twig or chaplin?

im trying with {% extends 'OroUIBundle:actions:index.html.twig' %} but i cant extend

tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize frontend view - you need to override twig templates.
Check this manual:
https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/current/dev-guide/customization#overriding-templates

Also check this example:
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomThemeBundle/README.md